# Extremely basic SQL Misunderstanding

Tags: mysql, database

I'm preparing for an exam in databases and SQL and I'm solving an exercise:

We have a database of 4 tables that represent a human resources company. The tables are:

```
 applicant(a-id,a-name,a-city,years-of-study),
 job(job-name,job-id), 
qualified(a-id,job-id) 
wish(a-id,job-id).
```

the table applicant represents the table of applicants obviously. And jobs is the table of available jobs. the table qualified shows what jobs a person is qualified for, and the table wish shows what jobs a person is interested in.

The question was to write a query that displays for each job-id, the number of applicants that are both qualified and interested to work in.

Here is the solution the teacher wrote:

```
Select q1.job_id
    , count(q1.a_id) 
  from qualified as q1
    , wish as w1
Where q1.a_id = w1.a_id 
    and q1.job_id = w1.job_id
Group by job_id;
```

That's all well and good, I'm not sure why we needed that "as q1" and "as w1", but i can see why it works.

And here is the solution I wrote:

```
SELECT job-id,COUNT(a-id) FROM job,qualified,wish WHERE (qualified.a-id=wish.a-id)
GROUP BY job-id
```

Why is my solution wrong? And also - From which table will it select the information? Suppose I write `SELECT job-id FROM job,qualified,wish`. From which table will it take the information? because `job-id` exists in all 3 of these tables.

Comment: cargo-cult programming. some people just blindly alias EVERYTHING in a query, because `q1` is so much easier to read than `qualified`.

Comment: If nothing else you have used hyphens where you should have used underscores. For example, `job-id` should be `job_id`

Comment: `- is not the same as _`

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the outputs off both queries?

Comment: wait, the _ was in teachers solution. so the teacher made a syntax mistake because the tables read - and not _. but apart from that, since I don't even count that as a mistake...Is there a logical mistake here on my side? with my answer?

Comment: @MarcB it's not just cargo cult programming. Aliasing tables is done for readability, and with larger queries, it is practically indispensable and should be done.

Comment: Note also that comma style joins were effectively deprecated in 1992. And yes, it's good practice to alias each and every instance of a table.

Comment: I often read queries from paper. It's incredibly convenient to have the aliases so I don't have to make guesses about the source. But if there's only a single table I do feel it simplifies the query to not use them.

Comment: I alias even if the alias is longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will list non-existing jobs in case the database has orphan records in `applicant` and `qualified`, and might also omit jobs that have no qualified and willing candidates.

I'm not exactly sure, because I have no idea if there's any database that will accept `COUNT(a-id)` when there's no information about the table from which to take this value.

edit: Interestingly it looks like both of these problems are shared by [both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09d0c/1) [of the](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09d0c/2) solutions, but [shawnt00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30902773/7806) has a point: your solution makes a huge pointless cartesian of three tables: see it [without the group by](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09d0c/5).

My current best guess for a working answer would therefore be http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09d0c/6

Answer (score 1):

You can only refer to tables mentioned in the `FROM` clause. If it's ambiguous (because more than one has a column of the same name) then you need to be explicit by qualifying the name. Usually the qualifier is an alias but it could also be the table name itself if an alias wasn't specified.

There's a concept of a "natural join" which joins tables on common column(s) between two tables. Not all systems support that notation but I think MySQL does. I believe these systems usually collapse the joined pairs into a single column.

```
select q1.job_id, count(q1.a_id) from qualified as q1, wish as w1
where q1.a_id = w1.a_id and q1.job_id = w1.job_id
group by job_id;
```

I don't think I've worked on any systems that would have accepted the query above because the grouping column would have been strictly unclear even though the intention really is not. So if it truly does work correctly on MySQL then my guess is that it recognizes the equivalence of the columns and cuts you some slack on the syntax.

By the way, your query appears to be incorrect because you only included a single column in a join that requires two columns. You also included a third table which means that your result will effectively do a cross join of every row in that table. The grouping is going to still going to reduce it to one row per `job_id` but the count is going to be multiplied by the number of rows in the `job` table. Perhaps you added that table thinking it would hurt to add it just in case you need it but that is not what it means at all.